# Black background when WebView is loading Flash animation

Tags: android, flash, webview

I am displaying a series of Flash animations in a WebView.  The screen goes black each time I load a new animation—this is visually distracting and I would like it to leave the screen white.  I have tried changing the WebView background color, embedding the Flash animation in HTML and specifying the background color, and making the WebView “Invisible” until the page has finished loading but nothing seems to have the desired effect.  The Flash animation does not display the black background when run on a PC.

I am completely stumped.  Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095977/screen-blinking-when-using-a-webview-with-flash

Answer (score -1):

Quiet for a year. Apparently solved via another question (see comments). Posting this as a community courtesy to get this question off of the unsolved list. A better answer would be appreciated, and thank you.

[**Here is the link that apparently solves this question.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095977/screen-blinking-when-using-a-webview-with-flash)

Comment: not working anymore