# Screen blinking when using a webview with flash

Tags: android, adobe, webview, flash

Edit: I made a demo apk, so you can understand what I mean: http://cl.ly/3g0s1p030j243y0p3m2F

For my application, I want a kind of "Super Power Point", or a keynote (the commercial team will present the product to their customers) using all the Android goodness, gestures, etc... on an Android tablet. As Honeycomb is not yet ready and because we need it before march, we choose some random Froyo Tablet (Archos 101), but my issue is for every tablet/phone I tried.

I made a really great application, but for some animations during the presentation, the customer wanted to use flash animations. Because I couldn't code animations (sort of little movies/ animated graphics) that easily in Android and the lack of time, that seemed to be a good idea.

So, after some search on the Web, I used webview and this code:

```
    WebView mWebView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    mWebView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView1.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/graph_01.swf");
```

This work pretty well, but on every device I tried (Archos 101, Nexus One, Nexus S, Galaxy S, Xperia, Desire, HTC Hero, and really more) every activity with a webview blink, a few milliseconds of black screen, then the animation finally appear.

PS: My layout is quite simple too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<WebView android:id="@+id/webview1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"></WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me, I cannot imagine I am the only one to face this issue.

Thank a lot for any help. You have all my code and the demo apk.

Comment: I have noticed this behavior on the android browser... I fear you might have to wait a long time before it gets fixed...

Comment: @Profete162 can you share me your project files please...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**THIS ANSWER ADDED LATER:**

So the problem is that Adobe's Flash Player creates a `SurfaceView` inside the `WebView` and there is a delay between the `SurfaceView` appearing and the Flash engine bothering to draw anything. In that small gap the SurfaceView appears totally black.

The solution I've found is to subclass WebView and add a customized SurfaceView to the view tree. Secondly it is also important to suppress the first draw() call to the Adobe view. The code for my subclassed WebView is as follows:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout;

public class FixAdobeWebView extends WebView {

    View whiteView;
    private boolean eatenFirstFlashDraw;

    public FixAdobeWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        whiteView = new WhiteSurfaceView(context);
        whiteView.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(800, 480, 0, 0));
        addView(whiteView);
    }


    private class WhiteSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        public WhiteSurfaceView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            getHolder().addCallback(this);
        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { }
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { }
    }


    //
    // Override drawChild to eat the first draw of the FlashPaintSurface
    //
    @Override 
    protected boolean drawChild (Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {
             if (!eatenFirstFlashDraw && child.getClass().getName().equals("com.adobe.flashplayer.FlashPaintSurface")) {
                 eatenFirstFlashDraw = true;
                 return true;
             }
        return super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
    }
}
```

The layout XML should declare an instance of this class, i.e. :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >
<org.test.FixAdobeWebView android:id="@+id/webview1" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

On my Nexus One running CM6.1 this works perfectly in that the WebView appears as solid white until the Flash SurfaceView starts drawing. You will probably need to adapt it a bit, e.g. get rid of the hardcoded 800x480 dimensions, and also destroy the white SurfaceView once it's no longer needed.

<strike>ORIGINAL (WRONG) ANSWER:</strike>

Looks like Adobe are to blame for this one.

The least awful workaround I've found so far is to :

1. Make the background of the WebView's parent a compatible colour (i.e. white).
2. Hide the WebView initially.
3. Wait until you get the page loaded event, and then queue a runnable to show the WebView after a one second delay.

It means you get a guaranteed one second delay before you can see anything, but it's less jarring than that horrible black flash afaik.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    >
<WebView android:id="@+id/webview1" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"    
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    ...
    final WebView mWebView1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    mWebView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView1.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override 
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mWebView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);                      
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
    mWebView1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/graph_01.swf");
```

There might be a better way though that would remove the need for a fixed delay...

It's been a while since I did anything with Flash but I seem to recall there is a way for the Flash control to use the browser's Javascript engine (a quick Google turns up the [Flex Ajax Bridge](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ajaxbridge_3.html) which seems likely).

What you could do is, with the aforementioned bridge, use ActionScript to call a Javascript function which does an alert(). In your Java code you'd hook your mWebView1 up to a `WebChromeClient` which implements [`onJsAlert()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onJsAlert(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.JsResult)). In that function you'd make the WebView visible.

Comment: Just tried your code, That seem to do what it's supposed to do ( I wait one second before seing something) but the black flash still appear... I also tried a 10seconds delay, but the black flash appear after a few instants while the webview is still invisible

Comment: Curses, sometimes it indeed doesn't work... seems that a SurfaceView is being created, and the black flash occurs between the surface being created and the Flash engine deciding to draw anything. What we need is to be a bit cleverer about hiding the webview...

Comment: @Profete162 I haven't forgotten about this question and plan to revisit it later today or tomorrow. Hoping to have some good news for you, but no promises.

Comment: Hello Reuben, I accepted your answer and voted up to give you all the bounty I promised. Unfortunately, the issue is not solved, as I said in first, post. Thank a lot for your help, I keep my fingers crossed even if I am strongly pessimist about having a fix.

Comment: @Profete162. I've done it! I'll update my answer v shortly... in a nutshell you need to stick another SurfaceView on top of the Flash one...

Comment: Just keep my fingers crossed to see a fix with Flash 10.2. Your explanations seem exciting but a little bit too complicated for me (how to  get rid of the hardcoded 800x480 dimensions, and also destroy the white SurfaceView once it's no longer needed.)

Comment: can you solve this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532303/problem-to-load-swf-file-in-android

Comment: This didn't work at all for me. I just get a white box painted whatever the width and height is you set in the constructor. IE:

"whiteView.setLayoutParams(new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(800, 480, 0, 0));"

Comment: Are you actually loading a .swf in the webview?

Comment: this is not working anymore it just shows a white rectangular.