# Integrating/embedding flash in Android applications ? Possible?

Tags: android, flash

From what i have googled out so far, it seems that we will have to host the flash file(swf) in a website and load the html page in the application in a webview... Is'nt there any other way to do it ?? Is there any library or something to integrate them ? Flash lite ?

Answer (score 2):

The following URL discusses a related question and has an example of how to load a local SWF into a webview. Of course this requires you to have Flash installed but you don't need the far too big AIR-Package installed.

[Screen blinking when using a webview with flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095977/screen-blinking-when-using-a-webview-with-flash)

Answer (score 0):

You're basically going through Adobe AIR for Android apps

Check out http://www.adobe.com/newsletters/edge/august2010/articles/article1/index.html?trackingid=HRTDI or http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Package_your_Adobe_AIR_applications_for_Ubuntu_and-17858.html or search for "Air for Android" in Google to get 100's of links